# How to query historical UTC time zone offset given a location and date

Tags: python, utc

I'm working on a script that builds schedules off of old airline timetables. In many places of the world, UTC local time and the observance of daylight savings time has repeatedly changed since the 1940's. I am looking for a user friendly way to query a country or city together with a date and get a UTC offset in return. For example, getting the UTC offset for Santiago, Chile on November 20, 1967 would return -4 whereas November 20, 1968 would return -3 as DST was not observed in the first part of the decade.

TimeAndDate.com has the data I need but you need to pay for an API for access. IANA has a historical time zone database but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it and it doesn't go back before 1970 from what I can see.

Any suggestions on the best/easiest way for a relatively inexperienced programmer to accomplish this in python?